# How to bypass account unlock prompt in geth console private testnet

Tags: security, testnets

How to bypass account unlock in private `testnet`, i want to transfer randomly between address. 
Is this possible, if yes how?

I am looking forward to bypass the prompt in console so that i can transfer to and fro by account index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unlock multiple accounts

In this case the argument to unlock is a whitespace delimited list of accounts addresses or indexes.

```
geth --unlock "0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1 0 5 e470b1a7d2c9c5c6f03bbaa8fa20db6d404a0c32"
```

If this construction is used non-interactively, your password file will need to contain the respective passwords for the accounts in question, one per line.

### Unlocking one account:

```
geth --password <(echo this is not secret!) account new
```

[source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#listing-your-current-accounts)