# Sending a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method

Tags: contract-development, web3js

Suppose I am doing like this

myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'}, function(error, transactionHash){
    ...
});

Do I need to unlock the account **0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe** to send the transaction ? 
If yes then what is the process to unlock this account. with **Web3 1.0**
I found [web3.personal.unlockAccount](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7658/16219) on a topic but didn't find any documentation about this in [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io)

Answer (score 1):

Web3 1.0 is still beta so something might not work or are incomplete.

Here is the documentation of [personal.unlockAccount](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_unlockaccount).

Answer (score 0):

When using the Mist Browser or MetaMask, you do not necccessarily have to unlock the account. They just take the transaction data, and sign a transaction for you.